Why is a doubtful eruv of bein hashamashos and nightfall ok, if b"hs itself is a doubtful status?
B"H
In the Rambam, hilchos Eiruvin chapter 1 halacha 21, it's said that the Eiruvin chatzeirus food has to be able to be eaten during the entire being hashamashos --twilight time; however, if it gets lost after it's "dark", then it still counts.
Then it said that if there's a doubt if it was lost during being hashamashos or during nightfall, then it's okay.

The eruv and the shituf must always be accessible, so that one may
partake of it throughout the time of beyn hash'mashot.80 For this
reason, if, before nightfall, an avalanche fell upon it, it was lost
or burned, or it was terumah and became impure, it is not considered
to be an eruv. If the above took place after nightfall, the eruv is
acceptable. If one is in doubt when this took place, the eruv is
acceptable, because whenever a doubt arises whether an eruv is
acceptable or not, it is considered acceptable.81
כא אֵין מְעָרְבִין וְלֹא מִשְׁתַּתְּפִין בְּשַׁבָּת אֶלָּא מִבְּעוֹד
יוֹם. וּמְעָרְבִין עֵרוּבֵי חֲצֵרוֹת וְשִׁתּוּפֵי מְבוֹאוֹת בֵּין
הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא סָפֵק מִן הַיּוֹם סָפֵק מִן
הַלַּיְלָה. וּלְעוֹלָם צָרִיךְ שֶׁיְּהֵא הָעֵרוּב אוֹ הַשִּׁתּוּף
מָצוּי וְאֶפְשָׁר לְאָכְלוֹ כָּל בֵּין הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת. לְפִיכָךְ אִם
נָפַל עָלָיו גַּל אוֹ אָבַד אוֹ נִשְׂרַף אוֹ שֶׁהָיָה תְּרוּמָה
וְנִטְמֵאת מִבְּעוֹד יוֹם אֵינוֹ עֵרוּב. מִשֶּׁחֲשֵׁכָה הֲרֵי זֶה
עֵרוּב. וְאִם סָפֵק הֲרֵי זֶה עֵרוּב שֶׁסְּפֵק הָעֵרוּב כָּשֵׁר:

The question: isn't the entire being hashamashos a doubtful status of day and night, with every passing moment being a doubtful status of either day or night?
If so then what's the difference between a doubtful nightfall and a "definite" being hashamashos? The entire being hashamashos doesn't seem to be it's own category of time, just a constant state of doubt of either day or night.

twilight is wholly a product of our ignorance of the precise point at
which one day ends and the next begins. Nevertheless, our ignorance
results in special laws that apply to this period.

